# CentOS: Tyring to install anaconda over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, anaconda

I'm new to Linux operating systems, so I hope this isn't a stupid question. I'm trying to install Anaconda on a CentOS Linux system over ssh. I've followed to instructions on the anaconda website. Using wget to retrieve the installer, and the bash command to install it.

All goes well, until after I accept the Anaconda Agreement by typing yes. I get a long list of Y's, all on a new line. And it seems the lists keeps expanding.

```
y
y
y
```

etc...

I have tried searching, but I couldn't find anything. It may be the problem that it is hard to search on problems for the letter 'y'.

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yes` is a command that does just that. It prints `y` (by default) forever. You can get it to print something else by giving that as an argument (e.g. `yes boo`).

So when you are typing `yes` thinking you are accepting whatever agreement you think you are accepting you are actually just running the `yes` command at your shell prompt.

What instructions are you following exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same situation before. It happens when you unintentionally press the "Enter" key while scrolling down, leading it to select the default "no" option when a yes/no question pops up.

To get past this, just take it easy while scrolling down, and when you encounter the yes/no question, go ahead and choose "yes" instead of accidentally hitting the "Enter" key :)